# Macbook wont work with lid closed

Tags: macos

Just received a macbook (on High Sierra OS but will update soon) that works ok with external display (with lid open and internal display also on), but when I close the lid (in order to only use the 2 usb-c connected external displays), all displays shut off and won't turn on until I open lid to enable the internal display.

This configuration works fine on a different macbook.  How can I fix so that it will work with lid closed?

Comment: Aswered here [Macbook Pro won't display external monitor when lid is closed - Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118055/macbook-pro-wont-display-external-monitor-when-lid-is-closed)

Comment: Or [How to use MacBook with lid closed, stop closed Mac sleeping | Macworld](https://www.macworld.com/article/673295/how-to-use-macbook-with-lid-closed-stop-closed-mac-sleeping.html)